# Как найти вероятность падения цилиндра на одно из оснований?

Tags: математика, геометрия, теория-вероятностей

Есть цилиндр высотой h и радиусом r, как найти вероятность его падения на одно из оснований?

Сейчас есть вариант просто посчитать площадь поверхности оснований и поделить ее на общую площадь поверхности. Получится (2πr^2)/(2πr^2 + 2πrh), но насколько этот ответ правильный?

Comment: С такой мутной формулировкой решение будет скорее фантазией, чем реальностью.

Comment: Вписываете цилиндр в сферу. Каждая точка поверхности сферы соответствует какой-то части цилиндра. Часть поверхности сферы, ограниченная одним из оснований соответствует вероятности падения на нее на нее. Делите площадь этой части поверхности на общую площадь поверхности - получаете вероятность.

Comment: @insolor Верно ли я понимаю, что вы считаете, что "цилиндр упал" означает, что произошло касание какой-то точкой цилиндра плоскости, на которую падаем?

Comment: @insolor да, все верно

Comment: Если цилиндр падает так, что его ось направлена под 45 градусов - на что он упал? В общем, задачу нужно нормально поставить.

Comment: @gbg приблизительно. Наверное не 100% корректно, потому что при касании ребром (когда "диагональ" сечения цилиндра вертикально) не обязательно будет равновесие. P.S. ну и не учитываются всякие отскоки, считаем, что если встал на грань, то уже все

Comment: Соглашусь с @insolor, подобные задачи, кстати, попадались — только не помню, здесь или в каком-то другом месте (типа, на сайте математиков). Что до равновесия — то просто рассматривайте вписанный цилиндр, и смотрите, где по отношению к точке касания находится вертикаль, проведенная из центра масс. Если не рассматривать упругие "подпрыгивания", то все именно так и получается, если подумать и порисовать схемы :) insolor, надеюсь, вы оформите свое предложение ответом.

Comment: @MBo это кольцо нулевой толщины, на общую вероятность падения на одно из оснований не повлияет

Comment: @insolor В принципе, из комментария Harry я понял, о чём может быть речь. Но про кольцо нулевой толщины автор не уточнял. А почему основания не закрытые? А может, это сплошное тело? В общем,  задачи пока реально нет.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю следующую модель: вероятность что цилиндр упадёт на одно из оснований заменить вероятностью того что случайный луч из центра цилиндра пройдёт через это основание. В случае полностью неупругого удара без угловой скорости это хорошая модель: цилиндр касается "земли" в произвольной ориентации. Если в этом положении вертикальный луч вниз из центра масс (геометрического центра цилиндра) проходит через основание, цилиндр встанет на это основание.

Из статьи про [телесный угол](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB#%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2) берем нужную формулу для конуса высоты `H` и радиуса `R`:

```
 omega = 2 pi (1 - H / sqrt(RR + HH))
```

У нас `H = h / 2`, `R = r`. `omega` - телесный угол. Делим его на `4 pi` чтобы получить вероятность падения:

```
 p1 = (1 - h / sqrt(4rr + hh)) / 2 - первое основание
 p2 = p1 - второе основание
 p3 = 1 - 2 p1 - боковая сторона
```

Comment: А почему H = h / 2?

Comment: Геометрический центр цилиндра (`H`) находится на половине его полной высоты (`h`).

Comment: Точно, спасибо)